# how to pass http data from service to controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, response

```
var locationListCtrl=function($scope, loc8rData){
 $scope.message = "Searching for nearby places";
   loc8rData
      .success(function(data){$scope.message = data.length > 0 ? "" : "No locations Found";
        $scope.data = { locations: data };
     })
      .error(function(e){
        $scope.message = "Sorry, Something has gone wrong";
        console.log(e);
     });
};

var loc8rData = function ($http){
  

     return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=33.7741195&lat=-13.9626121&maxDistance=20');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points:

- take into consideration, when you received one response from `$http` it's the common response (with status, headers, etc). So, if you want to access your data you will have to do: `response.data`
- Usually, when you have a service, you define multiple endpoints. So, you can return an object with multiple requests.

Check this little sample working: https://plnkr.co/edit/FNxEeVZti6D1wmLe

```
.service('PokeApi', function($http) {
  return ({
    getPokemon: function (name) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + name,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });      
    }
  })
})
```

And the controller is as simple as:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, PokeApi) {
  $scope.name = 'Plunker';
  PokeApi.getPokemon('pikachu').then(function (response) {
    $scope.pokemon =  response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, so how can i assign this response.data to a corresponding angular object in a .jade file?

Comment: It'd be a different question. And also, I'd need more context to help you :(. Why? Because there are different ways to have `.jade` files with angularjs. Based on your code and question I'd say:  change: ```.success(function(data){$scope.message = data.length > 0 ? "" : "No locations Found";
        $scope.data = { locations: data };
     })``` to ```.success(function(response){$scope.message = response.data.length > 0 ? "" : "No locations Found";
        $scope.data = { locations: response.data };
     })``` In this way you would be accessing the "expected object"

Comment: Other recommendation which I'd give you is: debug that part of the code in execution time in your local, to see what are you receiving. you can include the word ```debugger``` before `$scope.message = data.length` and try to ```console.log``` that data

Comment: This has been helpful. I have changed  as you suggested and it has worked perfectly. Thank you a lot

Comment: No problem! Was a pleasure. In that case, remember to mark the answer as accepted. :). @Mzala123